# C# How to override Dictionary ContainsKey

Tags: c#, dictionary, overriding

```
public class Date
{
    public int mm;
    public int dd;

    public Date(int get_mm, int get_dd)
    {
        mm = get_mm;
        dd = get_dd;
    }
}

public Dictionary<Date, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<Date, int>();

Date A = new Date(1,1)
Date B = new Date(1,1)

dictionary.Add(A,1);
if(dictionary.ContainsKey(B)) //returns false
...
```

How do i override the Date class in this situation?
I know the 2 objects is not the same, but don't know how to make it work

Comment: You need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `Date`.  Or you can create an `IEqualityComparer<Date>` to pass to the Dictionary to tell it how to compare the `Date` obejcts.

Comment: The best way to do is make the dictionary with a custom equality comparer. [Check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__)

Comment: Why do you want to get object B rather than object A from your exaple? A + B share the same values so why're you saving them twice?

Comment: @user743414 It's just an example. I just wanted to reflect my problem

Comment: @gaborbozo That's why I was asking what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways :

- By overriding the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method of you class Date.
- By using the `Dictionary` constructor that accepts one `IEqualityComparer<Key>` as argument.

It is not recommended to use the first method if your `Date` object is not immutable (i.e. that its attributes can't be modified after its creation => `Date` attributes need to be `readonly`). Because the Dictionary class builds its internal structure based on `GetHashCode` value at insert time. If the attributes used to compute the `GetHashCode` change, you won't be able to retrieve your objects already inserted in the dictionary.